# ¿Globo de Historieta con CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Estoy buscando generar con CSS un globo de historieta, es decir un globo de diálogo con texto y una "cola" del estilo que aparecen en comics. La solución en lo posible busca que la "cola" del globo posea un aspecto redondeado, tal como se muestra en la imagen: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Encontré una manera que [estoy publicando como respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/138023/127). Pero, ¿cómo podría mejorar el diseño del Globo de Historieta propuesto?

Comment: Si quieres autoresponder a tu pregunta hay una opción de publicar pregunta y respuesta al mismo tiempo cuando formulas la pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano resuelto!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yo te doy una forma de hacerlo, usando el seudoelemento `::before`.

En el html, yo usaria esta estructura:

```
<div class="vineta">
  <p class="globo"></p> 
</div>
```

Y en el css al div contenedor lo usaremos como referencia para posicionar al globo en unas coordenadas del cuadro.

```
.vineta{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 600px;
  /*Opcionalmente con box-shadow, creamos varias sombras, para simular un marco*/
  box-shadow: 
    0 0 0 1px black,
    0 0 0 6px white,
    0 0 0 7px black;
}
```

Ahora vendría el globo, el cual posicionamos de forma absoluta y unas medidas (las que quieras), lo único raro es que yo uso, `filter` para generar una sombra, pero porque esta es un poco diferente a como la genera la propiedad `box-shadow`, ya veras porque.

```
globo{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px; 
  top: 20px;
  left: 80px;
  border-radius: 2em;
  z-index: 1; 
  background-color: white;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px black) ;
}
```

Una vez creado el globo, vamos a crear la "colita", esta la hago usando `::before`, creamos un contenido vacío y la posicionamos en referencia al globo. Acá tenemos que acomodarlo de acuerdo a sus medidas, siendo algo así:

```
Ancho: Xpx; 
Alto: =(Ancho);
```

Y dependiendo de como lo posicionaremos, si arriba o abajo, izquierda o derecha, es que jugamos con las coordenadas en `X` y `Y`, así:

```
.globo::before{
   content: ''; /*o vacío, propiedad necesaria*/
}

.ejemplo-abajo-derecha::before{
   left: 50%; /*o lo que consideres*/
   bottom: (Ancho) / 2; /*O la mitad del ancho*/
}

.ejemplo-izquierda-arriba::before{
   top: 50%; /*o lo que consideres*/
   left: (Ancho) / 2; /*O la mitad del ancho*/
}
```

Para añadir ese efecto de triangulo, yo prefiero hacerlo con transform: skew(xgrados), así:

```
.globo::before{
   content: '';
   transform: skew(45deg);
}
```

```css
*, *::before{box-sizing: border-box;}

.vineta{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 90vh;
  max-height: 600px;
  /*Opcionalmente con box-shadow, creamos varias sombras, para simular un marco*/
  box-shadow: 
    0 0 0 1px black,
    0 0 0 6px white,
    0 0 0 7px black;
}

.globo{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px; 
  top: 20px;
  left: 80px;
  padding: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  z-index: 1; 
  background-color: white;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px black) ;
}

.globo::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -1;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  left: -5px;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="vineta">
  <p class="globo">contenido</p> 
</div>
```

El porqué uso drop-shadow, es porque este cubre en sombra el contenedor y lo que sobresale de este, sin importar la forma, además que si el elemento que sobresale, no tiene color de fondo o bordes, estos no se toman en cuenta en la sombra, un ejemplo:

```css
.sombra{
 padding: 1em;
 display: inline-block; 
 margin: 10vh;
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 position: relative;
}

.sombra::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 90%;
  top: 10%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30%;
  border: 10px whitesmoke solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.drop{
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px black)
}

.sombra{
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="sombra drop">sombra drop</div>
<div class="sombra normal">sombra normal</div>
```

### Actualización

Ahora, puedes hacer más dinámico todo, usando las `custom properties`, para hacer automático el calculo de las demás medidas en base al ancho de la colita.

Además descubrí cómo puedes lograr la curva, solo se trata de combinar las propiedades de box-shadow y border-radius, mira:

```css
*, *::before{box-sizing: border-box;}

.vineta{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  max-height: 600px;
  /*Opcionalmente con box-shadow, creamos varias sombras, para simular un marco*/
  box-shadow: 
    0 0 0 1px black,
    0 0 0 6px white,
    0 0 0 7px black;
}

.globo{
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: var(--borde);
  padding: var(--borde);
  --borde: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  z-index: 1; 
  background-color: white;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px black) ;
}

.globo.i{
  width: 150px; 
  top: 20px;
  left: 80px;
}

.globo.ii{
  width: 150px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}

.globo.iii{
  width: 150px;
  top: 60px;
  right: 10px;
}

.globo.iv{
  width: 150px; 
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 40%;
}

.globo::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -1;
  width: var(--colita);
  height: var(--colita);
}

.globo.abajo-derecha::before{
  --colita: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: calc( var(--colita) / -1.5);
  transform: skewY(30deg) rotateZ(-30deg);
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10em;
  box-shadow: 
    inset calc(var(--colita)/2) calc(var(--colita)/3) 0 0 white;
}

.globo.derecha-arriba::before{
  --colita: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  right: calc( var(--colita) / -1.5);
  transform: skewY(30deg) rotateZ(-120deg);
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10em;
  box-shadow: 
    inset calc(var(--colita)/2) calc(var(--colita)/3) 0 0 white;
}

.globo.abajo-izquierda::before{
  --colita: 50px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: calc( var(--colita) / -1.5);
  border-radius: 0 0 10em 0;
  box-shadow: 
    inset calc(var(--colita)/-3) calc(var(--colita)/4) 0 0 white;
}

.globo.izquierda-arriba::before{
  --colita: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: calc( var(--colita) / -1.5);
  transform: rotateZ(-60deg);
  border-radius: 10em 0 0 0;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 
    inset calc(var(--colita)/3) calc(var(--colita)/-4) 0 0;
}

.globo.yellow::before{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,0,.8);
  color: rgba(255,2,0,.5);
  animation: cambio-color ease 5s infinite both;
}

@keyframes cambio-color{
  45%,55% { 
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0); 
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="vineta">
  <p class="globo i abajo-derecha">
    abajo-derecha
  </p> 
  <p class="globo ii derecha-arriba">
    derecha-arriba
  </p> 
  <p class="globo iii abajo-izquierda">
    abajo-izquierda
  </p> 
  <p class="globo iv izquierda-arriba yellow">
    izquierda-arriba yellow
  </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Esta muy buena tu implementación! Yo comencé utilizando ::before también, el problema es darle el contorno "redondeado" a cola del globo. Eso me obligo a sacar el ::before y crear otros elementos! Tu implementación, agregando ese redondeado que menciono, quedaría muy bien!

Comment: Yo el borde, lo logró con el filtro `drop-shadow`, si te fijas. Aunque se ve mejor el mozilla. Por cierto, añadí más contenido a la respuesta para que fuera más fácil de usar en base a una medida.

Comment: Listo, ya logre descubrir cómo sería hacer la curva, la idea es usar 
**`border-radius`en una de las esquinas** y colocar una **sombra del mismo color que el fondo del globo de texto en los lados que forma esa esquina redondeada**, además de usar **`transform` para rotar o sesgar** la forma, hasta hallar la forma que quieras. Te recomiendo revises lo último y veas a qué me refiero.

Comment: tu propuesta es superadora! aún no logré investigarla a fondo (estoy en eso) pero sin duda funciona (más allá de alguna cosita sobre compatibilidad). Realmente me encanto, muy bueno! Las cosas que vea que se puedan ir mejorando las voy publicando! Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no necesitarías tantos elementos para poder hacer la pestaña de la viñeta. Te bastaría con utilizar el pseudo-elemento `:before` sobre el div sobre el cual tienes la viñeta.

En este caso, para simular el triángulo, he utilizado márgenes, ya que usando `width: 0` y `height: 0` cada uno de los márgenes tiende a formar un triángulo cuanto más grande lo hagamos.

Por último, para centrar el texto dentro del div tanto vertical como horizontalmente podrías utilizar `flexbox` para centarlo verticalmente mediante la propiedad `align-items: center` y, como es un texto, lo podrás centrar mediante `text-align: center;`.

**Nota:** He utilizado `transform: rotate()` para darle una inclinación que quedará acorde a la esquina de tu globo.

Ejemplo:

```css
#historieta{
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#historieta:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  left: 95px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 20px solid blue;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(75deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="historieta">
  <span>Esto es una prueba</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Si exacto! Yo comence utilizando ::before, pero al querer agregar a la cola el contorno "redondeado" no tuve "mas remedio" que agregar elementos... si se pudiera conseguir ese efecto redondeado sin necesidad de agregar elementos externos seria fantastico!

Comment: @Leandrohereñu He editado mi respuesta para amoldar el triángulo a la esquina. Para ello, he usado `transform: rotate()` para darle algo de inclinación y lo he amoldado correspondiente mediante las propiedades `top` y `left`.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo aquí como respuesta mi solución pero me gustaría conocer como lo harían ustedes, sobre todo con la Delta (Cola) del Globo, ya que en este caso tuve que utilizar varios Div para poder crearlo...

```css
.globo-historieta-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.globo-historieta {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.globo-historieta-dialogo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid darkblue;
  font-size: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60px;
}

.border-rigth {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  right: -42px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!-- PRUEBAS FORMAS -->

<div class="container">
  <!-- GLOBO DE HISTORIETA -->
  <div class="row">


    <div class="globo-historieta-container">
      <div class="globo-historieta-dialogo"></div>
      <div class="border-rigth"></div>
      <div class="globo-historieta">
        <span>Esta es una historieta</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perdona pero no consigo ver a que "cola" del globo te refieres.

Comment: mmm me parece que el render de stack por algun motivo no esta funcionando. Probalo en tu navegador copiando el codigo en un archivo .css y un .html por favor

Comment: Realmente si que la imprime pero la está dejando debajo del globo.

Comment: Tenes razon, es el padding usado en .globo-historieta para centrar el texto, que al estar fijo hace que el globo sea mas grande que la ventana permitida por stack, entonces queda debajo del globo

Comment: Usas muchos elementos, te sugiero una opción más limpia y te la explico en otra respuesta, revisala y me avisas :)